# Devuan - how to install non-free contrib?

Tags: devuan, free

I'm on transition from Mac OS-X to Devuan. Trying to make the learning curve not as steep, I need to install some non-free software. Reading through forums, I understand there is a command that will allow me to install Dropbox, skype, bluetooth audio outputs, etc. etc.on my system. I know this is highly discouraged, but I need these apps so as to let go of my Mac completeley, and then slowly do the complete migration into free software.

Comment: @GAD3R Looking at devuan, they do provide optional contrib and non-free repositories (even if it might be actually debian behind). eg:  http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/ascii/contrib/ and http://deb.devuan.org/merged/dists/ascii/non-free/

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks first:

- it might seem strange for newcomers from Mac OS X to choose Devuan, since MacOS itself didn't keep an original SystemV init system but is using `launchd` so there's anyway a new init system to learn (if one chooses to learn about it), whatever it would have been. Usually people choosing Devuan over Debian are already knowledgeable in this field.
- Devuan's site while [mentionning the availability of `non-free`](https://devuan.org/os/source-code#licensing) doesn't seem to document how to use it, probably expecting people choosing Devuan to already know.

So just find either in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` the entries about devuan with the word `main` and append `contrib non-free` to it. This should typically give something like:

```
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged ascii main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged ascii-security main contrib non-free
```

Remember to choose a source provided by the distribution whenever possible to avoid [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) or here FrankenDevuan. It might be a bit misleading here, because I believe (not sure) that `merged` in `devuan.org` plays the role of a kind of automatic reverse proxy which can dispatch the final URL either to devuan or to debian for untouched packages.

Comment: Thank you! I know this seems to go against the intention of what all of you are trying to achieve. I just need a couple of stepping stone that I will soon remove. I have given myself the task to learn this system so as to show others.